# How do i use and set custom listview adapter within a Thread?

Tags: android, multithreading, parameters, progress-bar, adapter

I'm a noob to android development and i am trying to show a progressbar while i populate a listview during onCreate.  I am trying to use a custom adapter, but eclipse is saying that my constructor is undefined. Specifically, "The constructor MainActivity.UserItemAdapter(new Thread(){}, int, ArrayList) is undefined"  It suggests that i change the context parameter on my custom adapter to thread.  Ideally, i would like to resolve this without having to change my constructor, because i use it elsewhere in my code.  Any help is greatly appreciated.  Here is my code.

On Create:

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


    dialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "Loading", "Loading, please wait..");
    Thread t = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
        //getting data for listview...   

    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListViewId);
    listView.setAdapter(new UserItemAdapter(this, R.layout.listitem, tweets));//<--error here constructor is undefined.

    handler.post(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            dialog.dismiss();                
          };              
      });        
    }           
 };
t.start();      
}
```

My Custom Adapter:

```
public class UserItemAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Tweet> {
    private ArrayList<Tweet> tweets;

    public UserItemAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<Tweet> tweets) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, tweets);
        this.tweets = tweets;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` refers to the Thread object in that case. User either `getApplicationContext()` or `MyActivity.this`.

Comment: Always use the `Activity` context if you know it's only valid within that context. Only use `getApplicationContext()` if there's a possibility that the task could still be executing between Activities and the use of the `Context` isn't tightly tied to that `Activity`.